# Parsing integers with JsonCpp

Tags: json, jsoncpp

I am using JsonCpp v1.6.5 to parse a JSON file that contains the following:

```
{ "some-property" : 32 }
```

After parsing the type of the value is `intValue` rather than `uintValue`.

How does the parser interpret an integer as unsigned?

Answer (score 0):

Everything below 2**31 is considered int, rather than unsigned int.

Comment: Can provide a reference to that?

Comment: I could find the parsing function in the source, but you could do it as well.

Comment: My point was is it documented anywhere (other than the code)?

Comment: No. JsonCpp is poorly documented.

Comment: Sorry, it is 2^31 rather than 2^32 .